# Adding attachments to each item in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list of 700+ items that I need to add to SharePoint. I know I can just copy/paste the items from excel in `Grid View` on SharePoint. But each item has it's own attachment, which is a PDF - only one attachment per item.  What's the easiest/shortest method to upload each item with it's attachment?

All I have right now is an Excel file of the names of the items only. Then the PDF's are still currently sitting in a folder on my computer.  I have not attached the PDF's to each item in excel.  For that, I'm thinking I'll have to write a script in `Python` - unless there is an easier method with SharePoint that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, the easiest way would be to build a **database table** to contain the items along with attachments, *MS Access* for example, and then [**export** to SharePoint list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-a-table-or-query-to-a-sharepoint-site-10d03c99-08f6-43ca-b210-7535097d0de6) using the OOB External Data Export option. But working on 700+ items is not an easy task to begin with.

There are other options though. You can use **PowerShell** commands to bulk add attachments to SharePoint list items, or using **REST API** instead.

Here are a few references in case you need them:
[SharePoint Online: Add Attachment to List Item using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-add-attachment-to-list-item-using-powershell.html) / [Upload multiple file attachments in sharepoint list using REST API On SharePoint Online.](https://anomepani.github.io/posts/upload-multiple-attachments-in-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api-on-sharepoint-online/)